# Не работает property в Django models

Tags: python, django

Не получается написать property для модели. Данные не обновляются в админ панеле.
Хочу что бы когда вводилось пользователем значение оно автоматически увеличивалось на 222

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    t_purpose = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    current_cashlesser = models.FloatField(default=0.00, null=True)

    def _get_amount_count(self, amount):
        amount += 222
        return amount

    @property
    def _current_cashlesser(self):
        return self._get_amount_count(self.current_cashlesser)
```

Пытался ещё вот так.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    t_purpose = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    current_cashlesser = models.FloatField(default=0.00, null=True)
   
    @property
    def _current_cashlesser(self):
        self.current_cashlesser += 222
        return self.current_cashlesser
```

Comment: Твой код работает как и нужно. После того как пользователь введет значение, значение в твоем проперти будет на 222 больше чем он ввел. Что бы увидеть это добавь вывод значения `_current_cashlesser` в админке. 
Или тебе надо, что бы после того как пользователь ввел значение, что бы увеличилось значение в поле `current_cashlesser`?

Comment: Пользователь вводит значение в поле, потом сохраняет и когда открываешь снова эту же запись значение уже больше на 222

Comment: Т.е. тебе нужно, что бы увеличивалось значение твоего поля `current_cashlesser ` а не то, которое хранится в @property?

Comment: Да. То есть что бы не создавалось новое поле а обновлялось текущее которое прописано в модели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если тебе нужно, что бы поле обновлялось автоматически, то ты можешь сделать это следующим образом
измени save в твоем классе `Transaction`

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.current_cashlesser:
            self.current_cashlesser += 222
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

минус этого подхода в том, что у тебя поле будет обновлятся каждый раз когда ты будешь сохранять объект(не только когда эти данные вводит пользователь)

если ты хочешь, что бы оно увеличивалось, только тогда когда вводит пользователь, тогда добавь увеличение этого поля в форму редактирования (можно в `save` можно в `clean`, сделаю для разнообразия в `clean`)

```
class TransactionEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction

    def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super().clean()
       current_cashlesser = cleaned_data.get('current_cashlesser')
       if current_cashlesser and len(self.errors) == 0:
          cleaned_data['current_cashlesser'] = current_cashlesser + 222
       return cleaned_data
```

теперь если ты редактируешь это поле из админки то в `admin.py` добавь что будешь использовать эту форму при редактировании

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TransactionEditForm


admin.site.register(Transaction, TransactionAdmin)
```